# Why django timezone offset is different?

Tags: django, timezone, timezone-offset

Django 3.2.10, Python 3.9

`settings.py`

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

`script.py`

```
from django.utils import timezone


tzinfo = timezone.localtime().tzinfo  # <class 'pytz.tzfile.Europe/Moscow'>
tz = timezone.get_current_timezone()  # <class 'pytz.tzfile.Europe/Moscow'>
dtz = timezone.get_default_timezone() # <class 'pytz.tzfile.Europe/Moscow'>

datetime_object = timezone.now()

print(datetime_object)                         # 2022-03-29 03:34:42.244830+00:00
print(datetime_object.replace(tzinfo=tzinfo))  # 2022-03-29 03:34:42.244830+03:00
print(datetime_object.replace(tzinfo=tz))      # 2022-03-29 03:34:42.244830+02:30
print(datetime_object.replace(tzinfo=dtz))     # 2022-03-29 03:34:42.244830+02:30
```

+0230 is not +0300, and the correct offset for this time zone is +0300.

Answer (score 0):

Using tzinfo when building timezone-aware datetimes is (from what I heard) a bad practice and can lead to bugs.

With

```
`TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

you should use make_aware:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime, time

local_now = timezone.localtime()

time_on_the_clock = time(5, 2)
timezone_aware_time = timezone.make_aware(datetime.combine(local_now, time_on_the_clock))

print(timezone_aware_time)
```

or using pytz:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

datetime_object = datetime.now()
moscow_time = timezone('Europe/Moscow').localize(datetime_object, is_dst=None)

print(moscow_time)
```